# get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) just return 1

Tags: php, functions, ajax

I've a custom post type, and I want to get the author ID inside a condition in my function.php, and it just return 1 - as I can see with var_dump and print_r. If I use the same function directly inside the single-teste.php, it return the author ID. But in this function, just zero. I've tried all the ways to get the Author Id inside this function, but nothing works. The "substract" function is working normally.

```
function example_ajax_request() {
    if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) {
        $fruit = $_REQUEST['fruit'];
        if ( $fruit == 'Banana' ) { 
          $user_id = get_current_user_id();
          $disponivel = mycred_get_users_balance($user_id);
          $author_id = get_the_author_meta('ID');
          while(isset($disponivel) && $disponivel >= 0){
            $descontou = mycred_subtract( 'penalty', $user_id, -10, 'Tipo de Compra');
            $pay_modelo = mycred_add('approved_comment', $author_id, 10, 'Teste');
            return $descontou;
            return $pay_modelo;
          } 
        }
    }
   wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
```

I call this function via ajax. I've no idea what can be the reason of it. Maybe someone has an idea?

Comment: You’re not inside the loop, so `get_the_author_meta()` returns information for the current user. What is the user an author of?

Comment: Hello, Jacob! Thanks for your answer. I'm accessing the site with a third account. There is the admin account, the author account and the subscriber account. I created a Custom Post Type, and I permite the author users to create posts in it. And when I access with the thrid account (subscriber), it should give points to the author, but it gives to admin. I've tried thousands ways of get author ID, but I was not able to make it works. What do you think about it?

Comment: it is single-teste.php

Comment: $author_id = get_queried_object()->post_author; this return NULL

Comment: $post_id = get_queried_object_id();
$post_author_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id ); This return String "1"

Comment: the_post(); // queue first post   $author_id_mt1 = get_the_author(); // echo author 
  rewind_posts(); // rewind the loop  --- also return 1 - admin

Comment: Because your code is in an AJAX response. There is no post. You need to send the author ID with the AJAX request.

Comment: Thank you, Jacob! I finally made this works.